# Sending email with API in node js

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, postmark

I've been trying to create an web application which sends welcome email to its new subscribers. from over one week i am just stuck at one problem, my console doesn't show any output, no success or fail of email sent. I've checked my API code and it works perfectly, tried everything but don't know why terminal is just not responsive
I try node server.js in my terminal and it says server running on port 3000, i navigate to local host 3000 through my browser and try hitting subscribe after entering my email and no updates in my terminal

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const axios = require('axios');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

// trying to create a server to send emails to users who click subscribe button

app.post('/send-welcome-email', async (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;

    const emailData = {
        From: 'sgarak@deakin.edu.au',
        To: email,
        Subject: 'Welcome to DevLink',
        HtmlBody: '<html><head></head><body><p>Welcome to DevLink, thanks for jooining our platform!</p></body></html>'
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.post('https://api.postmarkapp.com/email', emailData, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': `MY_API_TOKEN`,
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        res.status(200).send('Email sent');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send('Something went wrong');
    }
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .container {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  
  form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  label {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  
  input[type="email"] {
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  
  button {
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  button:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>DevLink Subscription</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Signup for our daily insider</h1>
    <form id="subscription-form">
      <label for="email">Enter your email:</label>
      <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
      <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Post the contents of `script.js`.

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser console ... CORS errors? There's no hint that you allow any CORS in your server code, and there will definitely be a preflight request since you're using JSON body parser i.e. you're sending json data

Comment: Did you check your api on Postman that rather its working or not?

Comment: API is working I've confirmed it

Comment: Don't have script.js for my code

Comment: I am not sure how to check browser console errors

Comment: POST command shows nothing as well, looks like terminal is just non responsive, no errors at all, nothing

Comment: Re: I am not sure how to check browser console errors 

Developer tool  (i.e. for chrome: Ctrl+Shift+i) -> Console tab

Comment: Don't use bodyParser. Use app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

Comment: @digitalniweb it throws error when trying to start server 
ReferenceError: bodyParser is not defined

Comment: I could see some problem in browser console, i'll share image in the post

Comment: Please research those error messages, you are not the first person ever to encounter them.

Comment: I've figured it out, it's working now

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot shows that you are trying to make the HTTP request to your server by running `curl` in the **same terminal** as you are running your server using `node`.

Because the terminal is running `node`, it isn't accepting new shell commands, so `curl` isn't running.

You need to run `curl` in **a different terminal**.